# Laravel: how to populate a blade SELECT with values from a where statement

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I understand you can send values to a select statement like this:

Controller:

```
$client = Client::lists('name', 'id');
return View::make('index', compact('client'));
```

And populate this in my view like so:

View:

```
{{ Form::select('client_id', $client, Input::old('client_id')) }}
```

But how do I populate only records from Clients where group_id = 1 for example.

I tried:

```
$client = Client::lists('name', 'id')->where('group_id', 1)->get();
```

and

```
$client = Client::lists('name', 'id')->where('group_id','=', 1)->get();
```

But it doesn't seem to work like that and gives me the error "Call to a member function where() on a non-object"

Any ideas on how to make it work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found an answer that worked for me:

Use fluent instead of eloquent, which will look something like this:

```
$client = DB::table('clients')->where('group_id', 1)->lists('name');
return View::make('index', compact('client'));
```

Then in your view just call it inside blade form tags like this:

```
{{ Form::select('client_id', $client, Input::old('client_id')) }}
```

@KyleK, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Isn't a bad practice to call directly a table by name?

Comment: Yeah, should probably be using the model here.

Comment: Also `lists()` is now deprecated. Adrian's answer is better.

Answer (score 10):

Controller:

```
$client = Client::where('group_id', 1)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

View:

```
{!! Form::select('client_id', $client, Input::old('client_id'), ['class'=> 'form-control'])  !!}
```

Result:

```
<select id="client_id" class="form-control" name="client_id">
  <option value="1">John</option>
  <option value="2">Karen</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `lists` is deprecated now use `pluck`

Answer (score 9):

The lists() must be called at last

```
$client = Client::where('group_id','=', 1)->lists('name','id');
```

Comment: `lists()` is now deprecated. Adrian's answer is better.

Answer (score 6):

This would work too

```
Client::where('group_id','=', 1)->lists('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a typo or not, but you're not retrieiving properly,

This line should be...

```
    $client = Client::lists('name', 'id')->where('group_id','=', 1)->get();
```

Also....

Sometimes when populating lists, you will get models, and its easy to pass them, but sometimes u get arrays (fluent, raw etc) , and in those cases you have to access manually, and build the form with HTML because you have to access it differently.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - I'm getting an error with this "Call to a member function where() on a non-object" do you know why that would be? It's signalling out the line you proposed above.

Comment: @kylek  if i have array of id than its not working.   ('group_id','=', $ids)   here, $id contains[1,2,3,]. what to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use Laravel's query builder (e.g. for performance reasons):

```
$clients = DB::table('clients')->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
return view('index', compact('clients'));
```

or, with a `select` to pull only what's needed:

```
$clients = DB::table('clients')->select('name', 'id')->get()->pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();
return view('index', compact('clients'));
```

In your view:

```
{!! Form::label('client_id', 'Client') !!}
{!! Form::select('client_id', $clients, old('client_id')) !!}
```