# Getting the number of an object in array, but not the object itself. - Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object

I have this problem here with my query.

In my getIndex method I'm listing an array of objects from a table and then in my postIndex when I'm trying to post them it turns out that I'm posting the number of the object in the array, but not the object itself. Why is this happening, someone?

```
public function getIndex() {

    $user = Auth::user();

    return view('educator.account.account',[
        'user' => $user,
        'class'=> ClassSubject::where('teacher_id','=',$user->id)()->lists('class_id'),
        'subject'=> ClassSubject::where('teacher_id','=',$user->id)->lists('subject_id'),
    ]);
}

public function postIndex(Request $request) {
   ClassSubject::where([
        ['subject_id','=',$request->input('subject')],
        ['class_id','=',$request->input('class')]
    ])->get();
```

The form:

```
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class=" panel-heading" id="admin-heading"> Добре дошли!</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <br>
            {!! Form::open(['action' => 'Educator\AccountController@postIndex', 'class' => 'form form-vertical' ]) !!}
              <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-4">{!! Form::label('class','Избери клас:') !!}</div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">{!! Form::select('class', $class, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>
              </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <div class="col-md-5">{!! Form::label('subject','Избери предмет:') !!}</div>
                <div class="col-md-6">{!! Form::select('subject', $subject, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}</div>
            </div>
            <div align="center">
                <br>
                <br>
                {!! Form::submit('Избери', ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) !!}
            </div>
            {!! Form::close() !!}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Could you give us the code of the form you're submitting?

Comment: So your problem is that when you submit your form you will get the index id of the array and not the ID of the ClassSubject row?

Comment: Which Laravel version you are using?

Comment: @chanafdo The question title says laravel 5.2

Comment: @Dees040 My bad, missed that part :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you in getIndex():

```
return view('educator.account.account', [
    'user' => $user,
    'class'=> ClassSubject::lists('class_id', 'YOUR_HUMAN_READABLE_FIELD')->where('teacher_id', $user->id)->get(),
    'subject'=> ClassSubject::lists('subject_id', 'YOUR_HUMAN_READABLE_FIELD')->where('teacher_id', $user->id)->get()',
]);
```

Let me know if it worked or not.

**EDIT**

The problem has been fixed, this did the trick:

```
DB::table('class_subject')->where('teacher_id', $user->id)->pluck('id', 'name');
```

Comment: Now i'm not getting my information in the drop down at all

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add '->get()'. I've updated my answer.

Comment: **Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()**

Comment: @YoannaMurdjeva Maybe you can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17916806/2783759)

Comment: You can add my Skype (same as my username here) and i will help you fix the error, because it should be a 'simple' problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you are passing only one parameter you will receive an array with its values set to the column you are passing to `lists` method.

But `Form::select` uses array's `keys` for values of options and `values` for the display names of options.

So use the `lists` method as following.

```
ClassSubject::lists('displayName', 'value')
```

**In laravel 5.2 lists method is deprecated and consider using the `pluck` method instead which has the same signature.**